# failed to sen data to server angularjs

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, angularjs

i am getting an error while posting new data using `%http.post` . I have made a category at backend with django, and status i am writing in the field like i got in option fields in django backend model

`{"error_message": "Cannot resolve keyword 'category' into field. Choices are: id, inventory, name, slug", "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n\n "}`

my django model look like this.

```
from django.db import models

class Inventory(models.Model):
    APPROVAL_CHOICES = (
        (u'Good condition', u'Good condition'),
        (u'Bad condition', u'Bad condition'),
        (u'Broken', u'Broken'),
    )
    name         = models.CharField(max_length=255,  help_text="Enter inventory name")
    slug         = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    description  = models.CharField(max_length=255,  help_text="Enter inventory description")
    count        = models.IntegerField(max_length= 255, help_text="Enter count of Inventory", default=1)
    category     = models.ForeignKey('Category',  help_text="Enter category")
    location     = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="Enter inventory location")
    status       = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=APPROVAL_CHOICES,  help_text="Enter inventory statuss")
    published    = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.name


class Category(models.Model):
    name         = models.CharField(max_length=255,  help_text="Category name")
    slug         = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.name
```

Using angularjs i am trying to post a request to the server using tastypie api

```
$scope.createInventory = function(){
        var data = {"name":$scope.newinfo, "description":$scope.newinfo,"count":$scope.newinfo, "location":$scope.newinfo, "category":$scope.newinfo, "status":$scope.newinfo};
        $http.post("http://api.bos.lv/api/v1/inventory/?format=json", data).success(function (data, status, headers) {
            alert("Inventory Added!");
                $http.get(headers("location")).success(function(data){
                    $scope.info.push(data);
                });
        });
    };
```

Then i am using this form

```
<td><input type="text" ng-model="newinfo.name"></td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="newinfo.slug"></td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="newinfo.description"></td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="newinfo.location"></td>
    <!--<td><input type="text" ng-model="newinfo.count"></td>--->
     <td><select ng-model="newinfo.category" ng-options="inventory.category.name for inventory in info.objects"></select></td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="newinfo.status"></td>
    <td><button ng-click="createInventory()">Saglabāt</button></td>
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. You could improve your question by probing the problem until you're more certain whether your problem pertains to AngularJS or Django. And be sure to actually phrase your post as a question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify a category. You get an error, because django needs data for category. You can specify in django, `default=null` so you could not specify any category.